# How to send a transaction request to a Safe Wallet using Safe SDK?

Tags: transactions, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I would like to send a transaction request to Safe Wallet from my CLI tool using Safe SDK. Is it possible to do so in a Node.js environment?

I found this: [Programmatically sending a transaction request to Gnosis Safe wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134718/programmatically-sending-a-transaction-request-to-gnosis-safe-wallet) but it's outdated (packages changed and most likely the API). What's the proper approach now?

Answer (score 0):

new API URLs are:

```
ARBITRUM_ONE: "https://safe-transaction-arbitrum.safe.global",
AURORA_MAINNET: "https://safe-transaction-aurora.safe.global",
AVALANCHE_C_CHAIN: "https://safe-transaction-avalanche.safe.global",
BINANCE_SMART_CHAIN_MAINNET: "https://safe-transaction-bsc.safe.global",
ENERGY_WEB_CHAIN: "https://safe-transaction-ewc.safe.global",
GOERLI: "https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global",
MAINNET: "https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global",
POLYGON: "https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global",
EVMOS: "https://gateway.safe.evmos.org",
OPTIMISM: "https://safe-transaction-optimism.safe.global",
ENERGY_WEB_VOLTA_TESTNET: "https://safe-transaction-volta.safe.global",
GNOSIS: "https://safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global",
FANTOM: "https://safe-txservice.fantom.network",
BOBA_NETWORK: "https://safe-transaction.mainnet.boba.network",
```

I think the rest should work